# What is the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for five sets?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Anyone know where I can find the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for five sets?
I tried to use google but found nothing.  Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for 4 sets are: 
\begin{align}
&|A\cup B\cup C\cup D|\\[3pt]
&=|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|\Big\}\text{ all singletons}\\
&-(|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|A\cap D|+|B\cap C|+|B\cap D|+|C\cap D|)\Big\}\text{ all pairs}\\
&+(|A\cap B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap D|+|A\cap C\cap D|+|B\cap C\cap D|)\Big\}\text{ all triples}\\
&-|A\cap B\cap C\cap D|\Big\}\text{ all quadruples}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Yes you have to proceed in much the same way to get to 5 sets as well. In the case of 5 sets, you'll have five quadruples and one quintuple.

Answer (score 8):

All singles - all pairs + all triples - all quadruples + all quintuples.

Comment: Ok thanks I get it

Answer (score 2):

We have 
\begin{align}
|A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5|
=&
|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|+|A_4 |+|A_5|
\\
&
-|A_1\cap A_2|
-|A_1\cap A_3|
-|A_1\cap A_4|
-|A_1\cap A_5|
\\
&
-|A_2\cap A_3|
-|A_2\cap A_4|
-|A_2\cap A_5|
\\
&
-|A_3\cap A_4|
-|A_3\cap A_5|
\\
&
-|A_4\cap A_5|
\\
&
+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|
+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_4|
+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_5|
\\
&
+|A_1\cap A_3\cap A_4|
+|A_1\cap A_3\cap A_5|
\\
&
+|A_1\cap A_4\cap A_5|
\\
&
+|A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4|
+|A_2\cap A_3\cap A_5|
\\
&
+|A_2\cap A_4\cap A_5|
\\
&
+|A_3\cap A_4\cap A_5|
\\
&
-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3 \cap A_4|
\\&
-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3 \cap A_5| 
\\&
-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_4 \cap A_5| 
\\&
-|A_1\cap A_3\cap A_4 \cap A_5|
\\& 
-|A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4 \cap A_5| 
\\
&
+|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4 \cap A_5| 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The Inclusion-Exclusion principle for $n$ sets can be found here for future reference.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

The Pattern indeed continues, i.e.
$$|\cup^{n}_{i=1} A_i|=\sum |\text{Singletons}|-\sum |\text{Pairs}|+\sum |\text{Triples}|- \sum |\text{Quadruples}|+...+(-1)^{n+1} |\text{n-tuples}|$$

The inductive proof can be found here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inclusion-Exclusion_Principle

Just consider the additive function used in the proof to be the function returning the size of a set.
So if $|A|=n$, then $f(A)=n$