# permutation of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations

I have a question regarding the permutation of sets and it is:

**Problem:** let the sample space $X$ be the set of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, the permutation $\{n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5\}$ represents the object allocation where for $i,j\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ we have $n_i=j$ if person $i$ receives the object by person $j$. Furthermore $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. If we define the events:

$$A_i=\{(n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,n_5)\in X\space |\space n_i=i\}$$

**My confusions:** I do not understand how to list these elements under the defined set of element characteristics this set has for instance, in the sample space $X$, can $n_1=1, n_2=2,n_3=3,n_4=4, n_5=5?$

If not then the values $n_1$, $n_2$,... can take are $n_1=2,3,4,5; n_2=1,3,4,5; ...$ etc. So one possible element of the sample space is $(2,3,4,5,1)\in X?$.

But in the set $A_i,$ now there is a new condition which is $n_i=i$, that means the set $A_1=\{(1,1,1,1,1)\}?$. I am alittle confused on the definition of $n_i=i$ in the set $A_i,$ and how many elements  $A_1, A_2,...,A_5$ contains. Can anyone help me explain or find the elements of the set $A_i$, or just an example for$ A_1$ and $A_2?$ I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of a permutation as a bijective function from a set to itself (*rather than related definition of strings of characters each character being used once, etc...*) we have that $A_1$ is the set of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $1$ is mapped to $1$.

Equivalently, using the definition of permutations as strings of characters instead, $A_1$ is the set of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that $1$ is in the first position.

This includes but is not limited to $12345, 13524, 15243,\dots$ and does not include things like $23451$ or $54321$ since $1$ is not in the first position and further does not include things like $11111$ or $67890$ since these are not permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ (*the first fails to be a permutation since each character is only allowed to be used exactly once and the second failed because the characters used are not from the correct base set.  equivalently, the first wasn't bijective and the second had the wrong codomain*).

---

It is worth talking about then things like $A_1\cap A_2$ which are those permutations who simultaneously have the first *and* second terms as fixed points... containing things like $12345, 12543, 12453,\dots$, the first position necessarily being a $1$ and the second position necessarily being a $2$.

It is also worth looking at $A_1^c$, the set of permutations such that $1$ is *not* a fixed point.

Finally, of considerable importance is the set $A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap A_3^c\cap A_4^c\cap A_5^c$, the set of permutations on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ such that *none* of the elements are fixed points.  We call a permutation with no fixed points a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

---

As for counting these, for $|A_1|, |A_1\cap A_2|\dots$ approach directly with rule of product like usual.  For those positions whose values are not forced, pick what element appears in that position and take note of how many options you had given earlier such selections.  You have that $|A_1|=4!$ that $|A_1\cap A_2|=3!$ and so on.

These observations coupled with inclusion-exclusion will then even allow you to calculate the number of derangements, something I leave to you to finish on your own or to read about in the linked article.  I rather strongly suspect that calculating the number of derangements may even be a later part of the current question you are working on or a question to be asked very soon after completing this one since they are so closely related.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. Additionally then $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = 2!?$

Answer (score 1):

No, notice that $i$ is defined outside the characterization of the set. Meaning that $i$ is fixed for each set. So $$A_1=\{\color{red}{1},2,3,4,5),(\color{red}{1},2,3,5,4),(\color{red}{1},2,4,3,5),\cdots\}.$$
Also, notice that the tuple has to be in $X,$ and $(1,1,1,1,1)$ is not a permutation. 
It is not clear if by permutation you mean that you have to use every element in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$ If so, you will get $(5-1)!$ as the number of elements in $A_1$ because you are fixing the first one and then you have $4$ choices for the second one, and then $3$ choices...
If you allow repetition, then you will have $5$ choices in each of the remaining $4$ positions, so you will end up having $5^4$ elements in $A_1.$

Comment: Thank you so for instance in the set $A_1$, the number of possible elements are $4!$, same with $A_2, A_3, A_4,A_5?$. I can see that some of the element within these sets will overlap with each other when I need to count the total sample space am I right?

Comment: You are right. The other sets also contain $4!$ elements. Also yes, they overlap. For example $A_i \cap A_j$ contains $(5-2)!$ because now you are fixing two elements. I don't understand the last question tho.

Comment: So my question is the total sample space of all $A_1,...,A_n$ will be $5! = 120$. But this double counts the overlapping elements. 

Is this allowed? Or when I actually count the sample space I need exclude the overlapping elements so it wont actually be $120?$

Comment: Oh, not really. The union of that is $5!-D_n,$ $D_n$ is called the Derangement number and counts the number of permutatations without fixed points. Actually, you need the principle of inclusion exclusion to do this.

Comment: So essentially  i just have to subtract the overlapping intersection terms of the inclusion exclusion principle ? So for instance 5!- 3!-.... depending on the different possible combinations of the intersections?

Comment: If you have just $3$ sets. $A_1,A_2,A_3$ you can check that
$|A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3|=|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|-|A_1\cap A_2|-|A_1\cap A_3|-|A_2\cap A_3|+|A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3|.$
For the general formula, notice that you have to add all possibilities of every size till $5$ and alternating the signs.

Comment: Wait so are you basically saying I have to do this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235843/what-is-the-inclusion-exclusion-principle-for-five-sets to calculate the total sample space for this problem? Is there a faster way?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis "*Is there a faster way*"... your first time seeing the problem?  No.  This is the standard elementary approach to the problem.  Later times seeing the problem, recognizing the relationship to the problem of counting derangements?  Yes.  There are faster ways to calculate the number of derangements.  The fastest likely being $D_n = \left\lfloor \frac{n!}{e}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$, but to understand why this is true takes some effort.

Comment: Oh I see ok I understand. May I just check that the answer of the sample space is: 
$4!+4!+4!+4!+4!-10(3!)+10(2!)-5(1)!+0!?$

Comment: Yes! notice that $\binom{5}{2}=10=\binom{5}{3}.$ Can you put it in a sum together? That is one of the fastest ways. Is called Homogeneous inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Those coefficients appear ion the derangement formula derivation, wait I think I get it now when you mean by n! sybtracted by the derangement $D_n$. So essentially the sample space I followed from the five sets is correct right?

Comment: The formula is correct if you are trying to count the permutations with at least one fixed point. Yes. And so, the ones without fixed are all minus what you computed. So the connection with derangements. In all the conversation, however, I am still not sure what you mean by sample space. You mean the union event? The question has, as sample space, the permutations which are $5!$.