# Permutation of sets with fixed points problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

[image]

I asked some confusions regarding this in a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900373/permutation-of-sets) and now want to see if I am doing the problems correctly.

**My solutions**:
a) $\Omega$ sample space contains $5!=120$ elements.

b) by the inclusion exclusion principle $|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3|= 4!+4!+4!-(3!+3!+3!)+(2!)= 56$

d) $\frac{56}{120}$

I am not sure if this is correct could anyone help me see if I am on the right track?

Comment: exactly correct.

Comment: For reference, [here is the alluded to earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900373/permutation-of-sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is all correct. $A_i$ is the set of fixed permutations $n_i=i$ i.e., in which $i^{th}$ student collects his own gift.

So $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 $ describes when at least one of students $1,2,3$ collect their own gift.